# Search within documents in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a test setup of SP 2010 on a Win 7 machine. For some reason it is not indexing the contents of the documents in its doc library. It will find parts of a doc name but no strings within the doc contents. I have given the NetworkServices acct read rights to the docs lib, I have made sure full indexing has been run and verified that the lib itself seems to have the correct settings. By all accounts this should work. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed my problem by installing SP2010 on a Win 2008 VM . Just a regular standalone server. The search works right out of the box.